# Stratifications and constructible sheaves

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $S$ be a reduced scheme of finite type over a perfect (even finite or algebraically closed if you want) field and let $F$ a constructible $\overline{\mathbf{Q}}_l$-sheaf over $S$.

Why can we find a dense, smooth open subset $U$ of $S$ such that $F_{|U}$ is smooth ?

I know that constructible means that there is a stratification $(S_i)$ of $S$ such that $F_{|S_i}$ is smooth. My idea is that the open that we want to take is the union of the strata which contain the generic points. But I don't think those have to be open right ? If we know that the closure of every stratum is a union of strata (which is sometimes included in the definition of a stratification) then I think it would be true but I don't think this is required in the definition of constructible (see here : http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/05BE)

Now even if had found our dense open subset how do know it is smooth ? I think this is where we use the hypothesis on the field.